# Navigate a user when clicked on a box in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to figure out how I can create a navigation when clicked on a certain box. Basically when the user clicks a box, it should navigate to a composable screen. The user can then select what they want from the screen and then navigate back to the "start" screen of choices.

All my boxes are in a lazyRow. How can I acheieve this ? I have set up 1 sealed class of objects with different names. 1 Navhost with all the respective composable screens. How can I link the 2 together to create navigation for each respective Box(items) when clicked ?

Sealed class:

```
sealed class HobbiesItem(var route: String, var title: String) {

    object Item1 : HobbiesItem("Item1", "Item1")
    object Item2 : HobbiesItem("Item2", "Item2")
    object Item3 : HobbiesItem("Item3", "Item3")
    object Item4 : HobbiesItem("Item4", "Item4")
    object Item5 : HobbiesItem("Item5", "Item5")
    object Item6 : HobbiesItem("Item6", "Item6")
    object Item7 : HobbiesItem("Item7", "Item7")

}
```

NavHost:

```
@Composable
fun Navigation2(navController2: NavHostController) {

    NavHost(navController2, startDestination = HobbiesItem.Item1.route) {

        composable(HobbiesItem.Item1.route) {
            Hobbies01()
        }

        composable(HobbiesItem.Item2.route) {
            Hobbies02()
        }

        composable(HobbiesItem.Item3.route) {
            Hobbies03()
        }

        composable(HobbiesItem.Item4.route) {
            Hobbies04()
        }

        composable(HobbiesItem.Item5.route) {
            Hobbies05()
        }

        composable(HobbiesItem.Item6.route) {
            Hobbies06()
        }

        composable(HobbiesItem.Item7.route) {
            Hobbies07()
        }

    }

}
```

My LazyRow with the Boxes:

How it looks in Emulator: https://gyazo.com/cc62241a5ceb4769eeaebd42d241d27b

```
// Displays all the items in a lazyRow
@OptIn(ExperimentalSnapperApi::class)
@Composable
fun Trying(HobbyRowItems: HobbiesItem, onItemClick: (HobbiesItem) -> Unit) {

    val allStackHobbies = listOf(
        HobbiesItem.Item1.route,
        HobbiesItem.Item4.route,
        HobbiesItem.Item7.route,
        HobbiesItem.Item2.route,
        HobbiesItem.Item3.route,
        HobbiesItem.Item5.route,
        HobbiesItem.Item6.route
        )

    val allItems = remember { (allStackHobbies).map { it } }
    val horizontalContentPadding = 3.dp // Moves the content left or right of the LazyRow
    val boxSize = 115.dp
    val lazyListState10 = rememberLazyListState()

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        BoxWithConstraints {
            val halfRowWidth = constraints.maxWidth / 2


            LazyRow(
                state = lazyListState10,
                flingBehavior = rememberSnapperFlingBehavior(lazyListState10),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = horizontalContentPadding, vertical = 8.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(allItems) { i, item ->
                    val opacity by remember { derivedStateOf {
                        val currentItemInfo = lazyListState10.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
                            .firstOrNull { it.index == i }
                            ?: return@derivedStateOf 0.5f
                        val itemHalfSize = currentItemInfo.size / 2
                        (1f - minOf(1f, abs(currentItemInfo.offset + itemHalfSize - halfRowWidth).toFloat() / halfRowWidth) * 0.5f)
                    }
                    }
                    Box(
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .scale(opacity)
                            .alpha(opacity)
                            .size(boxSize)
                            .background(Color.Blue)
                            .clickable {
                                onItemClick.invoke(HobbyRowItems)
                                Log.d("Hobby", "Pressed Box")

                            } 
                    ) {
                        Text(item, color = Color.White)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is this line correct? 
                                onItemClick.invoke(HobbyRowItems)
or should it be onItemClick.invoke(item) ?

Comment: if I change it to item, I get the following error: Type: Mismatch, Required: HobbiesItem, Found: String

Comment: but I noticed that I havent used Navigation2(NavHost) anywhere yet, got any idea on where I need to call it/ use it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have set up 1 sealed class of objects with different names. 1 Navhost with all the respective composable screens. How can I link the 2 together to create navigation for each respective Box(items) when clicked ?

You are running into a problem because your `allItems` list contains only routes (strings) but your `onItemClick` callback wants the whole `HobbiesItem`.

What you can do here is instead of passing just a list of routes to your `LazyRow`, you can pass a list of all `HobbiesItem`s.
You could also [hoist](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) the items outside the `Trying` composable, which would make your composable stateless and would let you control the state outside of it.

```kotlin
// Displays all the items in a lazyRow
@OptIn(ExperimentalSnapperApi::class)
@Composable
// change the function signature
fun Trying(items: List<HobbiesItem>, onItemClick: (HobbiesItem) -> Unit) {

    // get rid of these
    // val allStackHobbies = listOf(...)
    // val allItems = remember { (allStackHobbies).map { it } }
    // `remember` is not needed anymore because `items` are now passed
    // into this composable as a parameter

    // ...

            LazyRow(
                // ...
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(items) { i, item -> // <-- change here to `items`
                    // ...
                    Box(
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            // ...
                            .clickable {   
                                onItemClick(item) // <-- change here to `item`
                                Log.d("Hobby", "Pressed Box")

                            } 
                    ) {
                        // you probably wanted to show the title here instead of the route,
                        // even though in your example both are the same?
                        Text(item.title, color = Color.White) // <-- change here to `item.title`
                    }
               }
           }
    // ...
}
```

Then, in your top composable (usually the composable in your main/landing Activity), where (I assume) you are currently displaying your `Trying` composable, you have to display the `NavHost` composable instead. In your case that would be your `Navigation2` composable.

So something like this (here I am assuming you are using the `ComponentActivity`, but is similar in other scenarios)

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            // if you already have a reference to the navController2
            // from elsewhere then remove the next line
            val navController2 = rememberNavController()
    
            MyTheme { // this would be the name of your theme
                // you can wrap this into a Scaffold in the future
                Navigation2(navController2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally you connect them together where you will be displaying your `Trying` composable, which I assume it would be your actual staring destination.

So make a new composable desination that calls your `Trying` composable and change the starting destination so that it uses the same route.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Navigation2(navController2: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController2, startDestination = "ItemList") {
        composable("ItemList") {
            val allItems = listOf(
                HobbiesItem.Item1, HobbiesItem.Item4, HobbiesItem.Item7, HobbiesItem.Item2,
                HobbiesItem.Item3, HobbiesItem.Item5, HobbiesItem.Item6
            )
            Trying(
                items = allItems,
                // navigating on an item click
                onItemClick = { item -> navController2.navigate(item.route) }
            )
        }

        composable(HobbiesItem.Item1.route) {
            Hobbies01()
        }

        composable(HobbiesItem.Item2.route) {
            Hobbies02()
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm now! I forgot to specify that I was actually using the navigation not on the ComponentActivity but instead inside another Navigation composable (NavHost) . However calling Navigation2 from within Navigation1(My primary navigation) still worked using your method. I am still learning to Hoist states away from the UI related items and into another composable/ Viewmodel but will continue to work on that front! Anyway, Appreciate the help and feedback!